# Simple example to get started with a browser based game

Tags: javascript, game, html5

Here is a "hello world" simple skeleton I wrote to get started on an HTML5/javascript game. I converted it from a python example provided in Coursera's "An Introduction to Interactive Programming in Python" which demonstrates how to start moving a ball around a canvas using arrow keys.

I did this as a learning exercise to get to grips with javascript. While I've got this code to pass jslint, I was wondering if more experienced javascript coders could suggest better ways of doing this.

```js
var canvas, context, ball_pos, vel, keys = {};

var BALL_RADIUS = 20;

function init() {
    'use strict';
    canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ball_pos = [canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2];
    vel = 4;
}

function draw() {
    'use strict';

    // draw background
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // draw ball
    context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.fillStyle = 'white';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(ball_pos[0], ball_pos[1], BALL_RADIUS, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
}

function keydown(evt) {
    'use strict';
    // mozilla based browsers return which and others keyCode
    var keyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    keys[keyCode] = true;
    // alert(keyCode)
    // 33 up right
    // 34 down right
    // 35 down right
    // 36 up left
    if (keys[37]) { // left
        ball_pos[0] -= vel;
    }
    if (keys[38]) { // up
        ball_pos[1] -= vel;
    }
    if (keys[39]) { // right
        ball_pos[0] += vel;
    }
    if (keys[40]) { // down
        ball_pos[1] += vel;
    }
}

function keyup(evt) {
    'use strict';
    var keyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    delete keys[keyCode];
}

function animate() {
    'use strict';
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    draw();
}

// register event handlers
window.onkeydown = keydown;
window.onkeyup = keyup;

init();
animate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `ball_pos` as an array with two elements to contain the `x` and `y` coordinate values of the ball,
it would be more natural to use a an object like this:

```
ball = {
    x: canvas.width() / 2,
    y: canvas.height() / 2
}
```

Instead of writing `keys[37]` and explaining with a comment `// left` what the number means,
it would be better to put that in a well-named variables, for example:

```
var KEY_LEFT = 37;
```

Then you can rewrite the conditions like this:

```
if (keys[KEY_LEFT]) {
    ball.x -= vel; 
}
if (keys[KEY_UP]) {
    ball.y -= vel;
}
```

Putting it together:

```js
var canvas, context, ball, vel, keys = {};

var BALL_RADIUS = 20;
var KEY_LEFT = 37;
var KEY_UP = 38;
var KEY_RIGHT = 39;
var KEY_DOWN = 40;

function init() {
    'use strict';
    canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ball = { x: canvas.width / 2, y: canvas.height / 2 };
    vel = 4;
}

function draw() {
    'use strict';

    // draw background
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // draw ball
    context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.fillStyle = 'white';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(ball.x, ball.y, BALL_RADIUS, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
}

function keydown(evt) {
    'use strict';
    // mozilla based browsers return which and others keyCode
    var keyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    keys[keyCode] = true;
    // alert(keyCode)
    // 33 up right
    // 34 down right
    // 35 down right
    // 36 up left
    if (keys[KEY_LEFT]) {
        ball.x -= vel; 
    }
    if (keys[KEY_UP]) {
        ball.y -= vel;
    }
    if (keys[KEY_RIGHT]) {
        ball.x += vel;
    }
    if (keys[KEY_DOWN]) {
        ball.y += vel;
    }
}

function keyup(evt) {
    'use strict';
    var keyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    delete keys[keyCode];
}

function animate() {
    'use strict';
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    draw();
}

// register event handlers
window.onkeydown = keydown;
window.onkeyup = keyup;

init();
animate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree about using x and y instead of an array. But I'm not so sure about using switch instead of multiple ifs: a problem I hit was to allow someone to press say up and left simultaneously to move diagonally (which is why the keys object is needed to store more than one downkey at a time). That's also why I've got lots of ifs instead of if else statements.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I dropped that point and fixed my post. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Also, Instead using "use strict" in every function, create an IIFE and put it in the beginning.